# React - Drag and Drop UML

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, uml

In the past I used a react UML library to create a react screen with drag n drop UML objects.  There was a pallet that the user could drag and drop the different shapes on the screen, including the connectors, to manually build a UML diagram.  I can't remember the name of that library.  All of the libraries I've found so far generate the UML from code. Which is nice but requires a lot more work to recreate what I'm trying to build.  The library I used had the drag and drop code already built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- react-digraph
- react-flow
- react-diagrams
- mxGraph (although this is not specific to React)

It's possible that the library you used was a custom-built solution or a less well-known library, so it may be helpful to review your code or project history to try to determine the specific library you used.

If none of these ring a bell or don't lead anywhere. Let me know if this helps or doesn't help

Comment: Thank you.  After taking a closer look at react-flow, I remember building the pallet and the dragging and dropping from it.  I used react-flow for everything else.